# How to get values from POST method for dynamic number of Div fields - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, list, post

Imagine this div; this div will be duplicated using an add more button according the user preference.

```
<div id='work'>
    <input type="text" placeholder="x" name="work_x[]" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="y" name="work_y[]" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="z" name="work_z[]"/>
</div>
```

Sample input data would be:

> IT intern
>    ABC solutions
>    6 Months
>
> Jr IT exec
>    CDE company
>    1 year

etc...

On submit In the backend using PHP I need to get the values to an array such as:

```
[[IT intern , ABC solutions, 6 Months] , [Jr IT exec, CDE company, 1 year]]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Cool! So what have you tried? SO is not a service that provides you code for free. Show what you have tried and where exactly you are stuck, we are glad to help solve those kind of problems!

Comment: A hint, the _POST variables for those values will be arrays that you will need to go through.

Comment: Also, don't give the div id work, give it a class if you are going to have duplicate elements

Comment: Hi loek I have tried the solution that are available to get the dynamic number of fields if it's only repeating a same field;

ex: if only one of the fields are repeating I can get the POST value using a single foreach loop.

But since these repeating divs has inter-related values I'm bit stuck at how to get them to a single array using loop.

Comment: delboy1978; In the JS I have created I have assigned a new id for repeating divs using 'work' + var . So it wont be an issue i guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first input (work_x) is mandatory, like this it should be good :

```
$i=0;
$data=[];
foreach($_POST['work_x'] as $val) {
    $data[$i]['work_x'] = $val;
    $data[$i]['work_y'] = $_POST['work_y'][$i];
    $data[$i]['work_z'] = $_POST['work_z'][$i];
    $i++;
}
```

or simpler and without named keys in array

```
$i=0;
$data=[];
foreach($_POST['work_x'] as $val) {
    $data[] = [$val, $_POST['work_y'][$i], $_POST['work_z'][$i]];
    $i++;
}
```